# How to change Zend 2 Model Datasource from a MySQL Connection to a JSON REST API?

Tags: json, zend-framework2

I'm currently developing a Zend 2 Projects which follows the MVC pattern.

All my models are filled with data from a MySQL Database using a direct connection.

Now without destroying my whole model-view-controller relations I would like to change the original datasource. The new datasource would be a JSON Rest API. This JSON Webservice contains basically the same data (just in another format) as the MySQL Source and is used as a webservice for our mobile applications.

The first problem is to get my Zend2 Application connected to the rest api. 
The second part would be to evaluate this data and to make it as some kind of a layer so that I could still use my "old" algorithms the same way as before.

What would be the best way to perform this kind of datasource switch? And is there any way to store the information delivered from the Webservice to lower the amount of queries to this webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write my model layer as a set of entities with mappers that know how to save and load the entities into the database. The mappers are interacted with via service classes and the rest of the application only ever uses the service classes.

As it's ZF2, I use ServiceManager to load the mappers into the service classes so that the service class doesn't know anything about the mapper (other than the method names to call) and the entities have no clue about the mappers that store them either.

With this scenario, I can write a new set of mappers that talk to a web service API rather than the database, reconfigure my Service Manager and everything will work as long as the new web service API mappers have the same methods as the database ones.